# Dynamically create HTML in Javascript using JS variables within HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to dynamically create HTML code with JavaScript using JS variables in the HTML tags. The code is then inserted into my HTML file via `.innerHTML`.

What isn't working (I didn't expect it to work really, but I'm not sure how to force it to work) is setting the `id` and `margin-right` attributes to JS variables (using `dynamicID` and `equalMargin` respectively).

```js
var numberOfImages = 7
var equalMargin = 1; //(divElement.clientWidth - equalWidth*7) / 6;
var dynamicCode = "";
var dynamicID = "";
var i;
for(i = 0; i < numberOfImages - 1; i++)
{
 dynamicID = "navDot" + i + "";
 console.log(dynamicID);
 dynamicCode = dynamicCode + '<img src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mvj24qzluobu098/seekDotEmpty.png?dl=0" alt = "emptyDot" id = dynamicID style = "max-height: 100%; margin-right = equalMargin;">';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just end the string, add the variable, and reopen the string.

Also, there are no spaces between attributes, the equals (`=`) sign and their values.

```js
var numberOfImages = 7
 var equalMargin = 1; //(divElement.clientWidth - equalWidth*7) / 6;
 var dynamicCode = "";
 var dynamicID = "";
 var i;
 for(i = 0; i < numberOfImages - 1; i++)
 {
  dynamicID = "navDot" + i + "";
  console.log(dynamicID);
  dynamicCode = dynamicCode + '<img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mvj24qzluobu098/seekDotEmpty.png?dl=0" alt="emptyDot" id="' + dynamicID + '" style="max-height: 100%; margin-right: ' +  equalMargin + ';">';
 }
```

Comment: You're a saint, and thanks for the stylistic pointer regarding spaces